# Here how to change root to vagrant for linux file permission?

Tags: linux, permissions, vagrant, root, sudo

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    vagrant    0 2015-07-27 11:56 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  194 2015-05-28 10:24 file2
```

Maybe this is not a good question. About file1, I am not sure how to change to vagrant as file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a file owner using `chown` command:

```
$ chown vagrant file1
```

From `man chown`:

> chown changes the user and/or group ownership of each given file. If
>   only an owner (a user name or numeric user ID) is given, that
>   user is made the owner of each given file, and the files' group
>   is not changed.

You need to run `chown` as `root` or use `sudo` as `file1` is already owned by `root`.